# Swift - Nodos pasan de un lado a otro con touchesMoved si el cuerpo physicsBody es muy delgado

Tags: swift2, spritekit

Tengo dos `SKSpriteNode` el gato y el muro negro, cada uno de ellos tienen asociada la clase `physicsBody` por eso el gato esta encima del muro negro.

El gato lo muevo con el dedo con la función `touchesMoved` de la siguiente forma:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if node == miaum {
            gato.position = location
            gato.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false 
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que como el gato sigue al dedo, cuando el dedo pasa de un lado a otro por el muro negro, el gato pasa también y eso no debería suceder. ¿Hay alguna forma rápida y fácil de programar para que eso no suceda?

Imagen que muestra el problema que sucede, muevo el gato con el dedo, según el código explicado anteriormente:

[image: Moviendo el gato con el dedo, según el código explicado anteriormente]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes utilizar las funciones propuestas por Sprite Kit para este tipo de casos. Las colisiones se deben manejar por el motor de física incluido y máscaras de colisión.

Te dejo un link de referencia: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html

Como dato adicional, te sugiero no modificar la posición directamente del "Gato", más bien cambiar la dirección y velocidad cuando lo muevas, así el detector de colisiones del mismo motor de Sprite Kit hará el trabajo.